# How do we detect keypresses in a sequence?

Tags: unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TrollingRowlandMK2 : MonoBehaviour {

    int cheat_progress = 0;
    float cheat_delay = 0.0f;

void detect() {if(cheat_progress == 0 && Input.GetKeyDown("1")){
            ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f; Debug.Log ("1 pressed");
    } else if(cheat_progress == 1 && Input.GetKeyDown("2")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 2 && Input.GetKeyDown("3")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 3 && Input.GetKeyDown("4")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 4 && Input.GetKeyDown("5")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 5 && Input.GetKeyDown("6")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 6 && Input.GetKeyDown("7")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 7 && Input.GetKeyDown("8")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 8 && Input.GetKeyDown("9")){
        ++cheat_progress; cheat_delay = 1.0f;
    } else if(cheat_progress == 9 && Input.GetKeyDown("0")){
        cheat_progress = 0;
        //Some cheats here
        Application.LoadLevel(3);

    }
    /*if(cheat_delay > 0.0f){
        cheat_delay -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(cheat_delay <= 0.0f){
            cheat_delay = 0.0f;
                cheat_progress = 0;}*/
        }
    }
```

We're trying to detect the keypresses and change the level, like a cheat code, but even when we debug, it doesn't seem to be detecting the keypresses.

Comment: Use Keycodes instead of strings . Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)); etc etc. also format your code pls.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining `Input.KeyDown()` and using a progress counter is a very rigid approach. You will find it difficult to modify or extend.

You may find [`Input.inputString`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) more adaptable.  On each frame it will hold the ascii value of any keys pressed since the last frame.  It could be used like this:

```
public string cheatCode = "1234567890";
public float timeoutDuration = 1.0f;

private string userInput = "";
private float timeoutTime = 0.0f;

public void Update() {
    if(Input.inputString.Length > 0) {
        timeoutTime = Time.time + timeoutDuration;
        userInput += Input.inputString;
        if(userInput.Contains(cheatCode)) {
            //activate cheat
        }
    }
    else if((Time.time > timeoutTime) && (userInput.Length > 0)) {
        userInput = "";
    }
}
```